# How can I create UML and ER diagram from existing rethinkDB ?

Tags: uml, entity-relationship, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

I have lots of tables in database in rethinkDB. so I want document whole system with ER and UML diagram.

Is there any way to generate ER or UML diagram from existing database ?

Or any thing which helps me to create easily ?

Comment: http://www.casestudio.com/enu/default.aspx

Comment: RethinkDB doesn't store metadata about table relationships, but you might be able to get that data for your diagram if you are using an ORM